# Matching all characters between < > having a range of length

Tags: bash

I want to capture and delete all characters between < > symbols (including <>) which have a length of between 2 to 5. The code should capture all these:

```
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <html>
    <body>
```

I tried things like with no avail:

```
sed 's/<.{2,5}>//g' file

sed 's/<...><....>$//g' file
```

This is the html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Skywalker Saga Star Wars Movies</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Movie title</th>
      <th>Release Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Episode IV: A New Hope</td>
      <td>1977</td>
```

The expected output should be this:

```
Skywalker Saga Star Wars Movies
Episode IV: A New Hope 1977
Episode V: The Empire Strikes Back 1980
Episode VI: Return of the Jedi 1983
Episode I: The Phantom Menace 1999
Episode II: Attack of the Clones 2002
Episode III: Revenge of the Sith 2005
Episode VII: The Force Awakens 2015
Episode VIII: The Last Jedi 2017
Episode IX: The Rise of Skywalker 2019
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think this post summarises html parsing pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Your mistake was referring to "the html file"; otherwise it might just have been text that resembled html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job on your sample data:

```
sed -n 's/.*>\(.*\)<.*/\1/p' test.html | grep -v "title\|Release" > tmp && { head -1 tmp ; tail -n+2 tmp | sed 'N;s/\n/ /'; }
```

Comment: I get this error when I run the code: bad flag in substitute command: '-'

Comment: You may not have entered the script correctly - it worked for me on linux and macOS - perhaps try copying the sample text that you've provided in your question into a new file called "test.txt" and copy and paste this command: `sed -n 's/.*>\(.*\)<.*/\1/p' test.txt | grep -v "title\|Release" | sed '2N;s/\n/ /'`

Comment: The second version of the code (all in one line) works great. Thanks. I do not know why the first version did not work. However, this code prints the movies release year on a new line. How should the code be modified so that the release year is in the same line separated by a space?

Comment: You're welcome; I've edited the answer to print the movie and the release year on the same line.